# Substituting values in sympy for a list gives the unexpected result

Tags: python, sympy, substitution

I want to do the following operation in which I feed in the index and it spits out the value that I want. However When I assign it the values it gives me the unexpected result.

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
i = sy.Symbol('i', integer=True)
j = sy.Symbol('j', integer=True)
a = sy.IndexedBase('a')
y=a[i, j]**2+3
y.subs({a:np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]),i:0,j:4})
```

I want the answer to be 5**2+3 = 28, but it gives me a[0, 4]**2 + 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IndexedBase` type doesn't seem to be implemented for accessing data (but rather for notation purpose). See at http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/indexed.html the following statement:

> The main purpose of this class is to allow the convenient creation of objects of the Indexed class. The **getitem** method of IndexedBase returns an instance of Indexed.

Maybe you could achieve what you want with a `Matrix` type?